# Iniciando SQL Server 2008 express r2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Galera, tô com um problema: formatei meu computador e não consigo iniciar o SQL Server 2008 Express R2. Quando clico no ícone para inicializar aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - Ocorreu um erro ao tentar acessar o arquivo de validação de licença. Reinstale o Sql Server para corrigir esse arquivo.

Eu instalei o SQL Server e o SQL Server Management Studio.

Eu já reinstalei varias vezes e não dá certo. Alguém me ajuda, fazendo o favor?

Arquivos utilizados para instalação:

- SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe
- SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe

Sistema Operacional: Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits

Comment: Precisa ser necessariamente o SQL Server 2008?

Comment: Eu utilizo pra desenvolver, se outra versão funcionar pode ser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A versão 2008 do SQL Server apresenta uma lista de problemas para sistemas operacionais mais recentes](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/2681562). É possível sim de instalar, mas envolve uma série de passos que são evitáveis se você partir para uma versão mais recente do SQL Server.

As versões 2012 e 2014 não apresentam qualquer impedimento para que você possa desenvolver. Experimente instalar uma delas ao invés de instalar a 2008.

- [Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 2 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-BR/download/details.aspx?id=43351);
- [Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=42299).

Comment: Essa versão Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Service Pack 2 Express; 

Quais arquivos do site preciso baixar? os mesmos que citei acima?(SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe
SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe)

Posso instalar o 2012 com o 2008 instalado?
A respeito de licença posso usar sem precisar pagar? ( não trabalho com desenvolvimento)
Obrigado!

Comment: Pode instalar com o 2008. Possivelmente o instalador vai pedir para atualizar a instância. Pode usar sem pagar.

Comment: Obrigado, instalei o SQL  2012